Using ThreadLocal vs RequestAttribute for accessing userId across application layers
I'm trying to decide between two approaches to access parameter across different layers (Controller, Service, Repository) in a Spring MVC application. For example:
Approach 1: Using ThreadLocal
public class UserContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Long> userIdHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
    public static void setUserId(Long userId) {
        userIdHolder.set(userId);
    }
    
    public static Long getUserId() {
        return userIdHolder.get();
    }
    
    public static void clear() {
        userIdHolder.remove();
    }
}

@Component
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        Long userId = // get userId from token or somewhere
        UserContext.setUserId(userId);
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        UserContext.clear();
    }
}

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/user/info")
    public String getUserInfo() {
        return userService.getUserInfo();
    }
}

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public String getUserInfo() {
        Long userId = UserContext.getUserId(); // Can access userId directly
        return userRepository.findUserInfo(userId);
    }
}

Approach 2: Using @RequestAttribute
@Component
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        Long userId = // get userId from token or somewhere
        request.setAttribute("userId", userId);
        return true;
    }
}

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/user/info")
    public String getUserInfo(@RequestAttribute("userId") Long userId) {
        return userService.getUserInfo(userId);
    }
}

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public String getUserInfo(Long userId) { // Need to pass userId as parameter
        return userRepository.findUserInfo(userId);
    }
}

My Question
Which approach is considered best practice in a Spring application? I'm particularly interested in:

What do experienced Spring developers typically choose?
Is there an official Spring recommendation?
Are there any specific scenarios where one approach is clearly better than the other?


This question is more focused on seeking best practices and recommendations rather than just comparing the technical differences.


I suggest a third approach, that works for Spring MVC (not for the reactive stack), but wraps the first ThreadLocal in a cleaner way.
You can define an holder UserIdHolder class and a configuration that defines it as a request scope bean, like this:
public class UserIdHolder {
  private Long userId;
  // Getters, setters
}

@Configuration
public class UserIdHolderConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Scope("request")
  UserIdHolder userIdHolder() {
    return new UserIdHolder;
  }
}

Then you can inject this into the interceptor and in each bean you need via @Autowired annotation; Spring will manage the instances of this bean, making this to be created each time for any request, and referring to the correct instance in running the downstream controllers / services / repositories beans.
@Component
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

  @Autowired
  private UserIdHolder userIdHolder;

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    Long userId = // get userId from token or somewhere
    userIdHolder.setUserId(userId);
    return true;
  }
}

And so on.
Using this, you won't have to manually clean the thread local at the end of each request, since it is all managed by Spring, and you won't have to manually pass this attribute as a parameter for each method or in the controller signatures.
